# How to properly use ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm new to ActiveMQ and having a hard time getting started.

I have my broker and truststore set up and I can see the handshake.
Whenever I deploy the app in Tomcat I log into ActiveMQ console and can also see
the other Queues and topics that are configured within the XML file.

The queues are configured like this

```
<bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="my/destinaiton"/>
</bean>
```

and this bean id is passed into JmsTemplate        (org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate)

I want to just start with creating a queue and passing a string value into this queue and work with the listener later.

My question.  I changed the constructor-arg value (my/destinaiton) just to see a change in MQ console and I saw the change  my/destinaitonNew. 
However, when I change the value back to it's orginal value (my/destinaiton) it stays the same (my/destinaitonNew).

I can restart MQ and even reboot my machine but that value stays the same.  Why is this?

Also, if I've configured my queue the same as the others in the app shouldn't I see it in the MQ console?

Comment: did you send at least one message into new queue ?

Comment: No.  I never saw my new constructor-arg value in MQ console.

Comment: you should check connection tab in ActiveMQ admin console, if none connections will be wounded - you should investigate connection problems.

Comment: Thank you it was a connection issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SSL with my server and I had to ensure my broker in MQ bin/env had a trusted Tomcat handshake.